# Problem with getting a response from the API in Russian

Tags: php, laravel, openai-api, laravel-api

In my Laravel application, I ran into a strange problem.
I get a response from the API, but everything is in spaces in Russian, and everything is OK in English. Please tell me how to fix it?

chatcontroller.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\MessageRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Message;
use OpenAI\Laravel\Facades\OpenAI;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ChatController extends Controller
{
    private $openAIRequest;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->openAIRequest = Http::withoutVerifying()
            ->withOptions(['timeout' => 120])
            ->withHeaders([
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . config('openai.api_key'),
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ]);
    }

    public function messages(Request $request, MessageRequest $messageRequest)
    {
        
        $prompt = $messageRequest->input('prompt');
        $proglang = $messageRequest->input('proglang');
        $framework = $messageRequest->input('framework');
        $size = $messageRequest->input('size');
        $lang = $messageRequest->input('lang');
        $message = 'Задокументируйте код на языке программирования: ' . $proglang . ' с использованием фреймворка: ' . $framework .
            ' Документация должна быть в формате: ' . $size . ' Объект - предназначение' . ' и написана на ' . $lang . ' языке.' .
            ' Код, который необходимо документировать: ' . $prompt . ' Если в поле для кода будет короткий код, то мы его всё равно описываем, а если код отсутствует, то сообщи об этом. Текже не повторяй в своем ответе мой запрос, сконкретизируся на документации';

       Message::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'prompt' => $prompt,
            'proglang' => $proglang,
            'framework' => $framework,
            'size' => $size,
            'lang' => $lang,
        ]);

        return $this->askToChatGPT($message);
    }

    private function askToChatGPT($message)
    {
        $question = $message;
        return response()->stream(function () use ($question) {
            $stream = OpenAI::completions()->createStreamed([
                'model' => 'gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct',
                'prompt' => $question,
                'max_tokens' => 2000,
                'temperature' => 0.3,
            ]);
    
            foreach ($stream as $response) {
                $text = trim($response->choices[0]->text);
                if (connection_aborted()) {
                    break;
                }
    
                echo "\n";
                echo $text;
                echo "\n\n";
                ob_flush();
                flush();
            }
        }, 200, [
            'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
            'X-Accel-Buffering' => 'no',
            'Content-Type' => 'text/event-stream; charset=utf-8',
        ]);
    }    

}
```

А также скрипт страницы с API:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit-btn", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form     = $("#ask-chatgpt-form");
    var formData = form.serialize();
    var textarea = form.find('textarea[name="prompt"]');

    var selectedproglang = $('select[name="proglang"]').val();
    formData += '&proglang=' + selectedproglang;

    var selectedframework = $('select[name="framework"]').val();
    formData += '&framework=' + selectedframework;

    var selectedsize = $('select[name="size"]').val();
    formData += '&size=' + selectedsize;

    var selectedlang = $('select[name="lang"]').val();
    formData += '&lang=' + selectedlang;

    generateChatBoxMessage(false, textarea.val());
    textarea.val('');

    function generateChatBoxMessage(isChatGPTMessage, messageText) {
        var template   = isChatGPTMessage ? $("#chatgpt-message-box-template").html() : $("#user-message-box-template").html();
        var messageBox = $(template);
        messageBox.find('#message-box-text').text(messageText);
        $('#chat-box').append(messageBox);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'chatgpt/ask',
        data: formData,
        success: function (answer) {
            generateChatBoxMessage(true, answer);
        },
    });
});

const source = new EventSource('chatgpt/ask' + encodeURIComponent(input));
source.addEventListener('update', function (event) {
    if (event.data === "<END_STREAMING_SSE>") {
        source.close();
        return;
    }
    result.innerText += event.data
});

// Обновляем скрытое поле при выборе значения в с-електоре
$('select').change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val(selectedValue);
});
```

P.S. If you don’t have enough information or code, then write in the comments and I will definitely supplement the question!

I tried to output the response to the console and also in a simple `div`.  The response also goes to the console, only not separated by a space, but through a line, and in an empty `div` also separated by a space.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Explain the foreach on $streams? just $response['choices'][0]['message']['content'] and by [this](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-response-format) your response from the chat should have '\n'.
Can you dump the text please.